# How to use explode with loop in PHP taking input from html textarea

Tags: php, html

For example: Input from user in text area will be as below:

```
123111_Testingzone
123222_Testinghouse
123333_Testingcity
```

Output should be in downloaded_file.txt and it should look like as below;

```
My testname is 123111
My testname is 123222
My testname is 123333
```

My process:

I try to take multiple input in each line in one textarea in html form. Trying to explode it in PHP and loop it to use it with predefined text and output as file.

- HTML CODE:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Test/title>
    </head>
    <header>
      <h1>Test_Page</h1>
    </header>

    <body>
      <form action="abc.php" method="post">
          <h3>Option1</h3>
          Test Name: <textarea name="testname1"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Download">
      </form>

    </body>
  </html>
  ```

  For PHP code, I want only first 6 letters of each line in text area and repeat it as many text enter and output in one file.
- PHP CODE:

  ```
  <?php

  $testname = $_POST["testname1"];
  $array = explode('\n',$testname);
  $filename = "downloaded_file.txt";
  $testid = substr("{$array}",0,6);
  foreach ($testid as $content)
  {
  $contenter = "My test name is {$content}";
  }
  $f = fopen($filename, 'w');
  fwrite($f, $contenter);
  fclose($f);


  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

  readfile($filename);


  ?>
  ```

I dont know where my code is wrong and how to correct it? Please help.

Comment: loop `$array` to check all line for the first six characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corrected version of your code. Comments inline.

```
<?php

// Initial input
$testname = $_POST["testname1"];

// Split on newline. You need double quotes here, as escape sequences for special characters like \n are not
// interpreted in single quoted strings
$array = explode("\n",$testname);

// Declare contenter string, outside foreach loop
$contenter = "";

// For each line
foreach ($array as $line)
{   

    // Take the first 6 characters
    $testid = substr($line,0,6);

    // Put testid in string, and append it to the $contenter string.
    $contenter .= "My test name is {$testid}\n";
}
// Write the whole thing to the file
$filename = "downloaded_file.txt";
$f = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($f, $contenter);
fclose($f);


header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: text/plain; ");

readfile($filename);


?>
```

Comment: it works fine but the problem is output is not on new line, its always on the same line :(

Comment: Nope it is in a newline. That's why I added a "\n" after the testid. Please have a look at the file after its written. Also, since what you are sending is a text file, you can change your content-type to "text/plain". You can change your encoding accordingly as well.

Comment: it doesnt work if i use this  ---> $contenter .= "My test name is {$testid} and {$testname}";

Comment: ```$testname``` is your entire POST input. I think you mean something else. Also, you need to add a newline character to the end of the string.

Comment: can you please correct the complete code and update it? I am not very good in coding...

Comment: What exactly do you need in the place of ```testname```?

Comment: I figured out, I just used $lines instead of $testname and it solves the issue and also used the \n for next line :).

Comment: Ah, so the entire line is the name of the test :-) Also, I have changed the Content-Type header in my answer as well to reflect the MIME type of the document you are sending

Comment: One more question, I am using $lines variable however it is doing unwanted line break after it? How can I take care of it ?? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: You can use the in-built trim() method to remove such characters => http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Great. Can you please use trim in my code and send it to me thr complete code? That would be a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you split the content:

```
$array = explode(PHP_EOL,$testname);
```

Then you loop through it:

```
foreach($array as $value){
  echo $value . '<br>';
}
```

Now you will see:

```
123111_Testingzone
123222_Testinghouse
123333_Testingcity
```

Within the loop, you should split by a delimiter "_".

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  $data = explode("_", $value);

  if(sizeof($data) == 1){ // make sure the delimiter is found and match the amount of splits, that should be 2 id:name -1.
    echo $data[0] . " is the number and " . $data[1] . " is the name<br>";
  } else {
    die("user did not post data on line '". $key+1 ."' properly.");
  }
}
```

Now you have all the data to store it in your file. And for the complete code:

```
<?php

  $testname = $_POST["testname1"];
  $filename = "downloaded_file.txt";
  $array = explode('\n',$testname);

  $f = fopen($filename, 'w');

  foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $data = explode("_", $value);

    if(sizeof($data) == 1){ // make sure the delimiter is found and match the amount of splits, that should be 2 id:name -1.
      fwrite($fh, "My testname is {$data[1]} and the id is {$data[0]}");
    } else {
      die("user did not post data on line '". $key+1 ."' properly.");
    }

  }
  fclose($fh);


  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Content-Length: ". filesize($filename).";");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

  readfile($filename);


?>
```

However, you can also just `echo` the data, instead of saving it to a file and then output it. It is the same, only you dont have to hassle with files. If you do this, make sure the headers are known before the output.

Comment: I am not very good. Can you send me the complete php code please? I am still lost :(

Comment: @ShahidShabbir I've updated, just note that this is written on SO, and not even tested but I will presume it will work.

Comment: Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' properly."' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2\xyz.php on line 16

Comment: @ShahidShabbir Well, that was unexpected indeed. Fixed & updated it. The problem was `1` cannot concat with a string adding a space resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for the required result

```
foreach ($array as $lines) {
    $testid = substr($lines,0,6);
    $contenter .= "My test name is {$testid}\n";
}
```

Instead of the following code

```
$testid = substr("{$array}",0,6);
foreach ($testid as $content)
{
$contenter = "My test name is {$content}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fopen`, `fclose`, `fwrite`, I use `file_put_contents`, as I personally have had issues with `fwrite` before.

Therefore, this should work;

```
<?php

$testname = $_POST["testname1"];
$array = explode(PHP_EOL,$testname);
$filename = "downloaded_file.txt";
$testid = substr("{$array}",0,6);
foreach ($array as $val)
{
    $arr_contents = explode('_', $val);

    $content .= "My " . $arr_contents[1] . " is " . $arr_contents[0] . "\n";
    // \n is a newline char.
}
$filename = "downloaded_file.txt";
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
// write to file

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = $request->get('testname1');
$skuList = explode(PHP_EOL, $value);

foreach ($skuList as $row)
{   
    $testid = substr("{$row}",0,6);
    $contenter = "My testname is {$testid}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code for array loop

```
foreach ($array as $content) {
        $contenter.= "My test name is ".substr($content, 0, 6)."\n";
    }
```